# Stack overflow when trying to use regex in java

Tags: java, html, regex, recursion, stack-overflow

I have read up on some articles on how to optimize regex but none of the answers (less groups, using {X,Y} instead of *) seemed to stop my regex from getting a stack overflow error.

I am trying to make a dynamic search through a file. Lets say i am searching for 'i bet you cannot find me' in a file that is pretty large (2-4 mb). My regex generator would generate the regex:

```
i(?:.|\s)*?bet(?:.|\s)*?you(?:.|\s)*?cannot(?:.|\s)*?find(?:.|\s)*?me
```

the idea to this regex is that it finds the exact phrase no matter what characters or white space comes between the words. However when i try to use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(generatedRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContentsAsString);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group())
}
```

I am getting a stack overflow error. I know that regex use recursion but it doesnt seem like this is that bad of a regex. Is there any way I can optimize this regex? Thanks!

ANSWER:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("i(?:.*)bet(?:.*)you(?:.*)cannot(?:.*)find(?:.*?)me", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

is the pattern/regex that I ultimately am using. Seems fast and no longer getting a stack overflow exception

Comment: What is the purpose of `(?:.|\s)`? Is it because `.` doesn't match line terminators, and you want it to? If so, use [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode, aka `(?s)`, like this: `(?s)i.*?bet.*?you.*?cannot.*?find.*?me`

Comment: have you tried using greedy `*` instead of reluctant qualifier `*?`

Comment: Also, since your regex doesn't have `^` or `$`, the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) mode is meaningless.

Comment: *Warning:* Since you're scanning a 2-4 mb file, what if `i` is at start of file and `me` is at the end of the file? That would make `println(m.group())` print pretty much the entire file. *Oops!*

Comment: I think I could get away with making all but the last one greedy. The last one should be greedy because if the ending word appears anywhere after the match the whole file up the last instance of that word will be mfgdx right? I will take out the multuline parameter thanks. I will activate dotall mode thanks, I didn’t know how to activate that.

Comment: If fixing the entire regex doesn’t work out, an alternative could be regexing or indexofing the seperate words and substringing (or something) the wanted parts. Edit: but I guess that no longer really counts as optimizing the regex

Comment: Never use `(.|\s)*?`. Always use `.*?`. `(?s)i.*?bet.*?you.*?cannot.*?find.*?me` and still it is not a good pattern.

Comment: After using dotall, removing the unnecessary reluctant qualifiers, and getting rid of the unnecessary MULTILINE option it does run successfully pretty fast. no more stack overflow! Thanks for the comments!

Comment: After using the above solution my regex is now catching the first 'i' before the rest of the patterns (which can be a large part of my file). How can I tell the regex to get the closest 'i' to the rest of the words?

Comment: `How can I tell the regex to get the closest 'i' to the rest of the words?` You can't ! Regex is not a counter, therefore ... The best you could do is to get the _last_ 'i' it encounters. Throw a `.*` in the beginning of your regex and add a capture group around the rest ( to reference the _sentence substring_).

Comment: Also, make all the fill in's `.*` because this is single back stepper and `.*?` is absolutely meaningless. And, lose the cluster group syntax `(?:`.*`)` it just slows the regex down (in this case).

Comment: you lost me. .*(i(?:.*)bet(?:.*)you(?:.*)cannot(?:.*)find(?:.*?)me) seems to be matching the whole file up to the sentence

Comment: @Andreas in one of your comments you mention that this could match almost the entire file. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @BlahMclean Add capture group around each word, then print the start indexes of each word, instead of the entire matched text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting a lot of backtracking because of your reluctant qualifiers `(*?)`. One way to prevent backtracking is to use atomic grouping `(?>X)`, and/or possessive qualifier `(*+)`.

According to the comments, you also prefer to capture only the "i" that is nearest to "bet" to reduce the length of the overall match. Since you want to get the closest 'i' to the rest of the words, then in the place where I added negative lookahead for word two, you would put also a negative lookahead for word one, right beside it. In other words, `(?!bet)` would become `(?!i)(?!bet)` or `(?!i|bet)`. I have edited the code below to include this requirement.

```
String fileContentsAsString = "ii ... bet ... you, ibetyouyou";
String regex = "i(?>(?!i|bet).)*+bet(?>(?!you).)*+you";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContentsAsString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

> i .... bet .... you
>
> ibetyou

**Explanation** [(source)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2102028?start=15&tstart=0):

> "The way a reluctant quantifier works is, each time it's supposed to try to match, it first tries to let the next part of the regex match instead. So it's effectively doing a lookahead at the beginning of each iteration, which can get pretty expensive, especially when the quantified part only matches one character per iteration, like .*?"

Comment: It seems to me you’re getting everything but the wanted groups, correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @S.Klumpers not true. the `(?:.|\s)` from @op are all non-capturing groups. he only captures `group()` which is the total match

Comment: This is true, those are non capturing groups because i dont really mind what is in between the words. @PatrickParker I switched to using dotall and took out unnecessary reluctant qualifiers which got rid of my stack overflow exception. At this point its hard to tell just how much the other changes you suggested will increase performance but I do thank you for educating me on the atomic grouping!

Comment: After using the above solution my regex is now catching the first 'i' before the rest of the patterns (which can be a large part of my file). How can I tell the regex to get the closest 'i' to the rest of the words?

Comment: @BlahMclean in that case, then in the place where I added negative lookahead for word two, you would put also a negative lookahead for word one, right beside it. In other words, `(?!bet)` would become `(?!i|bet)`